# How to extract NDVI time series from MOD13Q1?

Tags: shapefile, ndvi

I want to extract NDVI from MOD13Q1 Version 6.1.

Specifically, I want to calculate province-specific NDVI values for every 16 days for my study's observation time period (30+ years) for multiple provinces for a country.

I think I have to use GIS shapefiles for the boundaries of the provinces.

Finally, I want to average the calculated NDVI values for the observation time period and use that value to represent the greenspace for each province.

How can I go about doing this? I have no experience with any GIS software.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. This is a different site than others. Here the questions need to be asked with to-the-point attempts. You can try any software first and then ask here mentioning a specific problem.